# strcat(dest, "\something") - backslash not showing

Tags: c, backslash, string-literals

I got a problem with C programming string concatenation.

Why `strcat(dest, "\something")` will not have the backslash copied to `dest`?

You may wish to follow the example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *dest = "";
    char *test = "how \something";
    dest = (char *)malloc((strlen(test) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strcat(dest, test);
    // Expect to see "how \something", but showed "how something"
    printf("%s\n", dest);

    free(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use double backslash to print a single backslash

Comment: This has nothing to do with `strcat` and everything with the C syntax for string literals.

Comment: Might want to use `calloc(..., 1)` instead of `malloc(...)` to zero-initialize the output string. Or maybe `dest = malloc`, then `strcpy(dest, "")`, then `strcat`.

Comment: Ok... I am a newbibe.
I have modified my code to receive user input, so why a "\something" will show as "something", what is in strcat function that immediately do a escape sequence?

Comment: Do not edit your question after answers/comments had been given, as this might render those ununderstandable. Add stuff as addition. I therefore rolled back your last change.

Comment: Haven't you got the warning : `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s'`. You just ignore warnings. Don't you?

Comment: @alk noted. Will put a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> backslash not showing

Escape it:

```
   char *test = "how \\something";
```

---

The compiler should have warned you about this like this (GCC 4.9.2):

```
main.c:8:16: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s'
   char *test = "how \something";
```

---

Also this is not related to `strcat()`.

To prove this just do

```
puts(test);
```

and receive the same output.

---

> ```
>   but showed "how something"
> ```

Are you sure? I'd expected

```
how omething
```

---

Also

- `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.
- In C there is no need to cast `void`-pointers as for example returned by `malloc()`, nor is it recommended in any way.

So just do

```
  dest = malloc(strlen(test) + 1);
```

or so make the code safe against late changes of `dest`'s type do

```
  dest = malloc((strlen(test) + 1) * sizeof *dest);
```

---

**Addition**

As pointed out by [*anatolyg*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509868/anatolyg) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400859/strcatdest-something-backslash-not-showing#comment77762665_45400859) you are concatenating to an uninitialised `char`-array here:

```
  strcat(dest, test);
```

This invokes undefined behaviour, which is not good.

To fix this either do

- `dest[0] = '\0';` or
- use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`

to `0`-terminate `dest` and with this make the `char`-array a C-"string" before using it alike when passing it to `strcat()`.

- Or just use `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DavidYew: Interesting. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 17.04 using gcc 6.3. Do you mean there will be a difference in the result of the compilation?

Comment: @DavidYew: I use `gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2` in C11 mode and do *not* see the `s`.

Comment: @alk, but for my question, I am on C only. C11 is a C++11, right?

Comment: @DavidYew: "*... is a C++11?*" No, C11 is C is C11. :-) The latest official C Standard.

Comment: thank you for the enlightenment, C is not my forte, been a PHP mainly coder, and revisiting C after 20 years.... was using Turbo C++ 3.0 and Borland C back then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150529/discussion-between-david-yew-and-alk).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 separate problems in your code:

- You have an unsupported escape sequence in the string `"how \something"`. `\` followed by `s` is not recognised by the compiler and is interpreted as `s`, like `\"` and `\'` would be interpreted as `"` and `'` respectively.  To include a `\` in a string constant, you should escape it as `\\`.
- You concatenate `test` to `dest` with `strcat(dest, test);` but `dest` points to an uninitialized block of memory allocated by `malloc()`. You should use `strcpy()` for that.  Note that you could just use the POSIX function `strdup()`, if available on your system.

Less important, but worth considering:

- there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C (unlike C++).
- you should test the return value of `malloc()`.
- you should `const` qualify pointers pointing to string constants.  It is not strictly necessary but good practice to avoid various kinds of bugs.
- the value of `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *test = "how \\something";
    char *dest = malloc(strlen(test) + 1);

    if (dest != NULL) {
        strcpy(dest, test);
        printf("%s\n", dest);
        free(dest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.
But I thought my code has the malloc so there is memory allocated to accommodate the new string, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidYew: There is memory allocated for the new string, no problem there.  The string constant `"how \something"` must be written `"how \\something"` for the \ to be an actual character in the string.

Comment: Yes, thank you for inputs! I got to learn it from the discussion earlier with others too! 
It is really great to learn from all coders around!

Answer (score -1):

As @melepmene mentioned in comments, "This has nothing to do with `strcat` and everything with the C syntax for string literals."

To make you understand the problem with your code, I'm gonna answer your question with another question.

Expect what's the output of the following program, execute the program and check the output (obviously it'd be different from what you've expected if it isn't then you'd have not asked this question in first place) and then go and google "C syntax for string literals"

```
int main()
{
  printf("%s\n", "\how \is?");
  return 0;
}
```